# Using SnowBallAnalyzer with PyLucene

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, pylucene, snowballanalyzer

I'm trying to use SnowBallAnalyzer in PyLucene but I always get an error saying: InvalidArgsError when I try to create an instance of it like this:

`analyzer = SnowBallAnalyzer("Spanish")`

or

`analyzer = SnowBallAnalyzer("Spanish", STOPWORDS)`

What I really need is i.e if I search for "Fútbol", I should obtain the documents that have the word "futbol" or "fútbol". So... I would like to apply SnowBallAnalyzer to the text I would like to index an to the query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know pylucene very well as I only work with the java version but as far as I know pylucene is accessing the java implementation.

If this is the case you are missing the Version parameter in the constructor.

```
SnowballAnalyzer(Version matchVersion, String name, String[] stopWords)
```

As SnowballAnalyzer has been deprecated in lucene 3.1.0, I suggest you directly use the spanish analyzer.

```
SpanishAnalyzer(Version matchVersion, Set<?> stopwords)
```